# How to search a file?

Tags: java

Supposedly the user will enter their "ID #: 1203103" then after that it will automatically create a text file named 1203103.txt. How can I search the file name "1203103.txt" in the file directory?

```
String id = scan.nextLine();
File file = new File(id+".txt");
FileWriter fileWrite = new FileWriter(file);
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWrite);
System.out.println("Enter the ID # to search: ");
```

Comment: what is the data in file ? In which pattern you want to search ? a word, line, etc.

Comment: It appears like your prompt is after you take the input, but your file would be created when you write something to your `bufferedWriter` and then `close()` it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with this.

```
import java.io.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File dir = new File("C:"); //file directory
        FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                return name.startsWith("1203103"); //here is you file name starts with. Or you can use name.equals("1203103.txt");
            }
        };
     String[] children = dir.list(filter);
     if (children == null) {
         System.out.println("Either dir does not exist or is not a directory");
     }else {
         for (int i=0; i < children.length; i++) {
             String filename = children[i];
             System.out.println(filename);
         }
     } 
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the ID # to search: ")
String id=scan.next();
File f= new File(id+".txt");
if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) { 
    System.out.println("file exist");
}else{
    System.out.println("file doesn't exist");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code will create a new file if the file doesn't already exist. If the file **does** exist, it will be erased and an empty file created in it's place. In both cases, you will have a brand new, empty file. There is nothing to search.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to search through all the files in a directory:

```
for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (!file.isDirectory()) 
             System.out.println(file.getName()); //Match here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can browse all files within a directory (a `file`) using `list` (for String results) or `listfiles` (for file results)...

```
String directoryName = ...;
File directory = new File(directoryName);
File[] listOfAllFiles = directory.listFiles();
String[] listOfAllFileNames =  directory.list();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to search for it. You already know its name, so just need to check if it exists, and optionally if it's a file and not a directory:

```
File file = new File(fileName);

if (file.exists() && file.isFile()) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: your answer is insufficient  because you did not have enough explanations and sources.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String id = "kick";
        File file = new File(id + ".txt");
        FileWriter fileWrite = new FileWriter(file);
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWrite);

        File folder = new File("C:\\Users\\kick\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication191");

        // the list of files at specified folder
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        // go through the list of files to see if you can find file was named kick
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {

            // gives you access to each elements of listofFiles array name
            String filename = listOfFiles[i].getName();
            if (filename.startsWith("kick")) {
                System.out.println("found");
            } else{
                System.out.println("not found');
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: at least have some decency to tell me why you down voted me so I can correct my way. I am so curious to know why?

Comment: Some decency? Anyhow, I'll oblige: what you're proposing is the equivalent of dialing every number in the phone book when you already know the number you want to call.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen    see I down voted you and I explained why so everything is cool right now good luck :)

Comment: Some emotions? I think you're taking things a bit far. This is a Q&A site, not the Valentine's Day screening of Titanic. I told you what I think is wrong with your approach. It's inefficient.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I thought same thing so I down voted you good luck and stop harassing me